# JPA / Hibernate - subclassSubgraphs in NamedEntityGraph ignored

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, persistence

I'm using JPA 2.1 and Hibernate 5.3.3.
I have the following Entities with a NamedEntityGraph defined for GeoObject.

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
@NamedEntityGraph(
    name = "graph.GeoObject",
    attributeNodes = { @NamedAttributeNode(value = "histogram")},
    subclassSubgraphs = {
    @NamedSubgraph(name = "subgraph.A", type = A.class, attributeNodes = { @NamedAttributeNode(value = "pictures") }),
    @NamedSubgraph(name = "subgraph.B", type = B.class, attributeNodes = { @NamedAttributeNode(value = "artifacts") })
    }
)
public abstract class GeoObject extends ObjectBase {

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name="id", updatable = false, insertable = false)
    private Set<HistogramEntry> histogram = new HashSet<>();

    ...
}

@Entity
public class A extends GeoObject {

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinTable(joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="a_id"), inverseJoinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="image_id"))
    private Set<Image> pictures = new HashSet<>();

    ...
}

@Entity
public class B extends GeoObject {

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "b_id", updatable = false)
    private Set<Artifact> artifacts = new HashSet<>();

    ...
}
```

To get a list of all GeoObjects I make the following query:

```
final EntityManager em = getEntityManager();
final CriteriaQuery<GeoObject> query = em.getCriteriaBuilder().createQuery(GeoObject.class);
final Root<GeoObject> entityRoot = query.from(GeoObject.class);
final EntityGraph<?> objGraph = em.getEntityGraph("graph.GeoObject");

final String hint = "javax.persistence.fetchgraph";
final List<GeoObject> result = new ArrayList<>(em.createQuery(query.distinct(true)).setHint(hint, objGraph).getResultList());
```

The GeoObjects are all loaded in one SQL query as expected (including the histogram attribute). But for the pictures Set from A as well as the artifacts Set from B individual queries are generated for each object. Is there no way to construct an EntityGraph which results in a single query for all objects?

By the way, when I try to define the EntityGraph dynamically, like this:

```
final EntityGraph<GeoObject> objGraph = em.createEntityGraph(GeoObject.class);
objGraph.addAttributeNodes("histogram");
objGraph.addSubclassSubgraph(A.class).addAttributeNodes("pictures");
objGraph.addSubclassSubgraph(B.class).addAttributeNodes("lines");
```

I get an NotYetImplementedException in addSubclassSubgraph.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is related to an open hibernate issue, https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-10378